# polish in Reverse Polish Notation or Polish Postfix Notation

Tags: vocabulary

Upon reading [Reverse Polish notation - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)

> Reverse Polish notation (RPN), also known as Polish postfix notation or simply postfix notation, is a mathematical notation in which operators follow their operands, in contrast to Polish notation (PN), in which operators precede their operands. It does not need any parentheses as long as each operator has a fixed number of operands. The description "Polish" refers to the nationality of logician Jan Łukasiewicz,[1] who invented Polish notation in 1924.[2][3]

What does **Polish** mean here?

The definition from [polish | Definition of polish in English by Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/polish)

> Verb:  Improve, refine, or add the finishing touches to.
>   Noun: A substance used to give something a smooth and shiny surface when rubbed in.
>   Relating to Poland, its inhabitants, or their language.

Does it relate to Poland?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it relates to Poland, as stated in the last sentence of your quotation:

> "The description "Polish" refers to the nationality of logician Jan
>   Łukasiewicz,[1] who invented Polish notation in 1924."

Jan Łukasiewicz was of Polish nationality, i.e. he was from Poland.